# logcheck command does not work but log check-test works

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to listen to log file changes and trigger emails in case certain errors happen, currently testing this on mac.

i have executed

`brew install logcheck`

this worked, i am also able to test by executing

`logcheck-test -l backend/test.log -r /usr/local/etc/logcheck/violations.d/ticket`

but when i try to execute the `logcheck` command itself, i get error as **command not found**

Any ideas, thanks.